# convert a hexadecimal number stored as a String to its binary equivalent (String) and vice versa in Java. tried writing the code but can't get results

Tags: java, binary, hex

> So I tried writing the code for the program but when I run it, it
> takes infinite inputs but no outputs and there are no syntax errors. I
> don't get where I went wrong.

```java
import java.util.*;
class A5
{   
    public String dec2bin(char c)
    {
        int d=0;
        if(c>='A')
        {
            d=c-55;
        }
        else
        {
            d=c-48;
        }
        String b="";
        while(d>0)
        {
            int r=d%2;
            b=r+b;
            d=d/2;
        }
        while(b.length()<4)
        {
            b="0"+4;
        }
        return b;
    }
    public String hex2bin(String h)
    {
        String b="";
        for(int i=0;i<h.length()-1;i++)
        {
            char c=h.charAt(i);
            String b4=dec2bin(c);
            b=b+b4;
        }
        return b;
    }
    public char bin2dec(String b)
    {
        int bin=Integer.valueOf(b);
        int d=0,p=0;
        while(bin>0)
        {
            int dig= bin%10;
            d=d+dig*(int)Math.pow(2,p++);
            bin=bin/10;
        }
        if(d<10)
        {
            return (char)(d+48);
        }
        else
        {
            return (char)(d+55);
        }
    }
    public String bin2hex(String b)
    {
        while(b.length()%4!=0)
        {
            b="0"+b;
        }
        String hex="";
        for(int i=0;i<b.length();i+=4)
        {
            String b4= b.substring(i,i+4);
            char d= bin2dec(b4);
            hex= hex+d;
        }
        return hex;
    }
    public static void main()
    {
        A5 obj=new A5();
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a hexadecimal no.");
        String n1=sc.next();
        System.out.println("Decimal no.=" +obj.hex2bin(n1));
        System.out.println("Enter a decimal no.");
        String n2=sc.next();
        System.out.println("Hexadecimal no.=" +obj.bin2hex(n2));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Integer.parseInt` (with a radix of 16) to go from hex string to `int`, and `Integer.toBinaryString` to go from `int` to binary string.

Answer (score 0):

May you can use `sc.nextLine()` instead of `sc.next()` ?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A5 obj=new A5();
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a hexadecimal no.");
        String n1=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Decimal no.=" +obj.hex2bin(n1));
        System.out.println("Enter a decimal no.");
        String n2=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hexadecimal no.=" +obj.bin2hex(n2));
    }
```

The nextLine method read an input String until you hit an Enter.